# Estimating the parameters of a normal distribution of probabilities

Tags: normal-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, empirical-bayes

I know the question sounds weird or perhaps, silly. And my limited knowledge in statistics might have caused ambiguity in presenting the problem. But still, here's the case:

Suppose there's a population of bernoulli experiments and the probability of success of these bernoulli experiments follow a normal distribution

Suppose I draw, say, 20 sample randomly from those bernoulli experiments, and I run them one by one. Then I should obtain some success and some failures (which add up to 20),right? Say I do this sampling for several times, my question is, is it possible for me to use the results from these sampling to estimate the mean and variance of the distribution of probabilities of the bernoulli experiments? If yes, how can I do so? And if no, what data should I collect to do so?

Comment: You seem to be intuitively looking for some form of Bayesian analysis. But the choice of the normal distribution as the prior for the parameter of the Bernoullis is horrible: it doesn't even have the right support. Take a look: http://lesswrong.com/lw/5sn/the_joys_of_conjugate_priors/

Comment: A probability cannot follow a normal distribution. By construction, probabilities range in the $[0,1]$ interval, which then is the support of any distribution they may follow. The normal distribution ranges in $[-\infty, \infty]$. When we want to model the distribution of probabilities, we use the Beta distribution, which has support in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Zen This does not sound Bayesian at all: in Bayesian terms the question asks *how to estimate a prior distribution* given a collection of experimental outcomes. Alecos: The quibble over whether or not a Normal distribution is appropriate is just that: plenty of good analyses assume Normal distributions of quantities that have intrinsic bounds. We all know that an assumption of normality is a convenient *approximation* and does not include an implicit assertion that all real numbers are possible. A Beta might be more convenient here, but that is not clear without an analysis of this problem.